# Triggering anchor click within a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below code to trigger the anchor click within the table `compareTable`, but it does not seem to take any effect. Can any1 point out the solution?

```
$('#compareTable a').click(function() {
alert("hi");
});
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LSh4M/16/)

Comment: This does not trigger, this binds an event handler... and in your demo, there are no anchors (`<a>`) in the table...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<a>` tag doesn't exist at the time you bind that click handler. You can solve this by using `.delegate()` or `.live()` (or binding the handler when you create the element). The former is usually considered preferable, but I find you markup difficult, so I'll share a quick workaround with `.live()`. Simple as can be:

```
$('#compareTable a').live('click', function() {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's methods are two-folded. If you call them with empty arguments (that is, you don't pass any argument), then do what they mean. `$('#something').click()` means that it would be clicked. If you provide an argument which is usually a callback handler, they just register that handler. So, you should use:

```
 $('#copareTable a').click();
```

And of course, since you don't want to click those links without any reason, you probably should write this code in response to another event. Something like:

```
 $('#register').click(function(){
      $('#compareTable a').click();
 });
```

And also don't forget that `$('#comparetTable a')` is a collection of all anchor links inside that table. So if you send click directive, all of them would be clicked.